# why message it is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm a Node.js beginner.
WHERE IS THE PROBLEM AND HOW TO FIX IT'

When i start the command, in console i see the error:

```
if(!hp[message.author.id]){
  ^

  ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\natan11\Desktop\kurczak 1\index.js:36:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'my token';

const fs = require("fs");

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

let hp = require("./hp.json");

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {

  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if(jsfile.length <= 0){
    console.log("nie mogę znaleźć komendy.");
    return;
  }

  jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
    let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
    console.log(`${f} loaded`)
    client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
  });
});

client.on('ready', async () => {

  console.log(`${client.user.username} is online on ${bot.guild.size} servers`);
  client.user.setActivity("tutorials on TSC", {type: "WATCHING"});

});

if(!hp[message.author.id]){

  //this is problem

  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: 0
  };
}

let hpAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
let basepAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
console.log(`%{hpAmt} ; ${basepAmt} ; `);

if(hpAmt === basepAmt){
  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: hp[message.author.id].hp + hpAmt
  };
  fs.writeFile("./hp.json", JSON.stringify(hp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });
}

const PREFIX = '*';

client.on('message', message=>{

  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch(args[0]){
    case 'start':
      message.channel.send('*gra_się_rozpoczeła!')
      let VoiceChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "polE");
      if(VoiceChannel !=null)
      {
        console.log(VoiceChannel.name + " kanał został znaleziony " + " channel.")
        VoiceChannel.join()
      }
      break;
    case 'stop':
      message.channel.send('*gra_się_zkończyła!')
      message.reply('przstraszył się przegranej uciekł i zgubił za sobą całą stawke')
      if(message.guild.voiceConnection)
      {
        message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
      }
      break;
    case 'ping':
      message.channel.send('pong!')
      break;
    case 'gra':
      message.channel.send('gre rozpoczyna się komendą *start w tedy pojawiją się kurniki które wysyłają co 10s kure. kury da się levelować za pomocą pisania nestępujacych komend egg1,egg2,egg3... gra się kończy kto pierwszy zniszczy kurnik rywala miłej zabawy bok! ;-)')
      break;
    case 'baza1':
      message.reply('zostałeś pseniesiony do bazy1')
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "baza2");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Baza1");
      message.member.addRole(role);
      break;
    case 'baza2':
      message.reply('zostałeś pseniesiony do bazy2')
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Baza1");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "baza2");
      message.member.addRole(role);
      break;
    case 'koniec_baz':
      message.reply('już nie przynalerzysz do żadnych baz')
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "baza2");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Baza1");
      message.member.removeRole(role);     
      break;
    case 'egg5':
      message.channel.send('*twój_kurczak_nabił_2lvl')
      break;
    case 'twój_kurczak_nabił_2lvl':
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "1lvl");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "2lvl");
      message.member.addRole(role);
      break;
    case 'gra_się_rozpoczeła!':
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "1lvl");
      message.member.addRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "2lvl");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      break;
    case 'gra_się_zkończyła!':
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "1lvl");
      message.member.addRole(role);
      var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "2lvl");
      message.member.removeRole(role);
      break;
  }
})
client.on('message', msg=>{
  if(msg.content ===  "*test"){
    msg.reply('bot działa wszystko jest ok');
  }
})

client.login(token);
```

I am asking for quick help in solving so I will help a little and give you a version of `discord.js`

`Version: 11.4.2 ^`

It's up to filling, do not worry about it

```
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
xd doggo food
```

Comment: Is a message object defined before the line if(!hp[message.author.id]) ? because you are not checking for the existence of this object before attempting to read properties from it in the code you have provided. That will throw an error.

Comment: ok but how to write it

Comment: I cannot access the discord API from my current location. I can only say it's just like any other object. var message = { author: { id: '123' } }; This message has an author and the author has an id.

Comment: The `message` object is only defined in the `message` event (`client.on('message', message => {...} );`. You need to either put the code that requires the author's ID inside the event or create a function that will pass and take the parameters of `message`, activated in the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace this part of your code:

```
if(!hp[message.author.id]){

  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: 0
  };
}

let hpAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
let basepAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
console.log(`%{hpAmt} ; ${basepAmt} ; `);

if(hpAmt === basepAmt){
  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: hp[message.author.id].hp + hpAmt
  };
  fs.writeFile("./hp.json", JSON.stringify(hp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });
}
```

With:

```
client.on("message", async message => {

if(!hp[message.author.id]){

  // Not a problem anymore :)

  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: 0
  };
}

let hpAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
let basepAmt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) + 1;
console.log(`%{hpAmt} ; ${basepAmt} ; `);

if(hpAmt === basepAmt){
  hp[message.author.id] = {
    hp: hp[message.author.id].hp + hpAmt
  };
  fs.writeFile("./hp.json", JSON.stringify(hp), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this line is not reading the file correctly:

```
let hp = require("./hp.json");
```

Check to make sure that it's in the location you've indicated. The require statement should be parsing it.

Comment: There error is not about `hp`, Double check the code. `message` is not defined/referred anywhere before it's use.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for clarifying!